# How do you do exponentiation in C?

Tags: c

I tried "x = y ** e", but that didn't work.

Comment: Did you mean `e**y` rather than `y**e`?

Comment: Unless your base or 'y' is 2, in which you case you can do `1 << e`. As in, `1 << 3` = 8..

Answer (score 110, accepted):

use the `pow` function (it takes `float`s/`double`s though).

`man pow`:

```
   #include <math.h>

   double pow(double x, double y);
   float powf(float x, float y);
   long double powl(long double x, long double y);
```

**EDIT**: For the special case of positive integer powers of `2`, you can use bit shifting: `(1 << x)` will equal `2` to the power `x`. There are some potential gotchas with this, but generally, it would be correct.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is still true with compiler optimizations, but bit shifting is one of the fastest operations on the CPU. I would take that approach if possible.

Comment: i don't understand your answer... could you give some number plugged in example...

Comment: What part don't you understand? Was it the bit-shifting part? Generally speaking, `pow(2, x) == (1 << x)`

So, `pow(2, 4) == 16` and `(1 << 4) == 16)`

Comment: If you want a fast floating-point integral power of 2, you can use `ldexp` -- `ldexp(1.0, 100)` will give you 2**100.  Works for negative powers too.

Answer (score 42):

To add to what [Evan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213042/how-do-you-do-exponentiation-in-c#213043) said: C does not have a built-in operator for exponentiation, because it is not a primitive operation for most CPUs.  Thus, it's implemented as a library function.

Also, for computing the function e^x, you can use the `exp(double)`, `expf(float)`, and `expl(long double)` functions.

Note that you do **not** want to use the `^` operator, which is the *bitwise exclusive OR* operator.

Comment: I'm just learning C, and that ^ threw me for a major loop at first. I'm beginning to "get it" now, but your reminder is very valuable for me and (I'm sure) hundreds more like me. +1!

Comment: @AlexejMagura: Since 62^3 is an xor operation (0x3E ^ 0x03 in hex), the result is 0x3D (61), which is not the same as the cube of 62 (aka 238328 or 0x03A2F8).

Comment: @AlexejMagura: OK, that's curious.  Should we clean up these comments?

Answer (score 28):

`pow` only works on floating-point numbers (`double`s, actually).  If you want to take powers of integers, and the base isn't known to be an exponent of `2`, you'll have to roll your own.

Usually the dumb way is good enough.

```
int power(int base, unsigned int exp) {
    int i, result = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < exp; i++)
        result *= base;
    return result;
 }
```

Here's a recursive solution which takes `O(log n)` space and time instead of the easy `O(1)` space `O(n)` time:

```
int power(int base, int exp) {
    if (exp == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (exp % 2)
        return base * power(base, exp - 1);
    else {
        int temp = power(base, exp / 2);
        return temp * temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: it'll work fine if you cast you int to a double/float and then back to int.

Comment: Inefficient, though, and rounding error *will* make a difference when the result gets near INT_MAX.

Comment: https://pl.wikibooks.org/wiki/C/Zaawansowane_operacje_matematyczne#produkt_(_iloczyn)

Comment: btw the log n solution is called binary exponentiation. It works for any associative operation, such as matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to an earlier answer, this will handle positive and negative integer powers of a double nicely.

```
double intpow(double a, int b)
{
  double r = 1.0;
  if (b < 0)
  {
    a = 1.0 / a;
    b = -b;
  }
  while (b)
  {
    if (b & 1)
      r *= a;
    a *= a;
    b >>= 1;
  }
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The non-recursive version of the function is not too hard - here it is for integers:

```
long powi(long x, unsigned n)
{
    long p = x;
    long r = 1;

    while (n > 0)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 1)
            r *= p;
        p *= p;
        n /= 2;
    }

    return(r);
}
```

(Hacked out of code for raising a double value to an integer power - had to remove the code to deal with reciprocals, for example.)

Comment: Yes, O(1) space O(log n) time makes this better than the recursive solution, but a little less obvious.

Answer (score 3):

or you could just write the power function, with recursion as a added bonus

```
int power(int x, int y){
      if(y == 0)
        return 1;
     return (x * power(x,y-1) );
    }
```

yes,yes i know this is less effecient space and time complexity but recursion is just more fun!!

Answer (score 2):

```
int power(int x,int y){
 int r=1;
 do{
  r*=r;
  if(y%2)
   r*=x;
 }while(y>>=1);
 return r;
};
```

(iterative)

```
int power(int x,int y){
 return y?(y%2?x:1)*power(x*x,y>>1):1;
};
```

(if it has to be recursive)

imo, the algorithm should definitely be O(logn)