# Why does my recursive function in C cause a stack overflow?

Tags: c, function, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm trying to make a function calculating x to the power n (where x could be a double, n must be an `int`). A recursive algorithm would be [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFbva.png), but implementing it in C gave me the stack-overflow error.

I tried finding my answer here, but the closest I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213042/how-do-you-do-exponentiation-in-c/213897), which didn't satisfy my needs.

Here is my code:

```
double power_adapted(double x, int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (n == 1)
        return x;
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
        return power_adapted(power_adapted(x, n / 2), 2);
    else
        return x * power_adapted(power_adapted(x, (n - 1) / 2), 2);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is called too often; every call to a function generates a seperate stack frame on, well, the stack. Then it's probably time to find a better algorithm.

Comment: The thing is, I got this algorithm from my teacher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think what you're trying to accomplish makes sense.

If you take a look at this part of code,

```
else if (n % 2 == 0)
    return power_adapted(power_adapted(x, n / 2), 2);
else
    return power_adapted(power_adapted(x, (n - 1) / 2), 2);
```

While the nested calls *may* present no problem (as a statement), the call on the outside always has `n = 2` and the base cases depend on `n`.

#### Solving the problem:

By taking a look at the formula provided, I think you should have a base case for `n == 2` to return `x * x` (this is the simplest change to the algorithm). So, the algorithm could be stated as follows:

```
double power_adapted(double x, int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (n == 1)
        return x;
    else if (n == 2)
        return x * x;
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
        return power_adapted(power_adapted(x, n / 2), 2);
    else
        return x * power_adapted(power_adapted(x, (n - 1) / 2), 2);
}
```

Comment: I'm sure the algorithm (picture in question) is right (got it from my teacher). How is my code not a translation of that? I can't seem to find my mistake.

Comment: Change the outer `power_adapted` call to `pow` which is a function of `math.h` or add a base case for `n == 2` to return `x * x`.

Comment: I will try to add that base case (I'm not allowed to use math.h). Could you tell my anyway where I made my mistake when translating that screenshot to C?

Comment: @MartijnLuyckx The screenshot is also "wrong" for the same reason. Perhaps your teacher wanted you to solve the error, perhaps it's just badly-expressed. Either way the algorithm in the image assumes you have a separate way of handling x^2.

Comment: Thanks! Marked as corrrect

Answer (score 5):

The recursive calls always pass 2 as n, so they will always trigger another recursive call.

I think you misinterpreted the formula.  I would interpret it as:

```
else if (n % 2 == 0) {
    double v = power_adapted(x, n / 2);
    return v * v;
}
else {
    double v = power_adapted(x, (n - 1) / 2);
    return x * (v * v);
}
```

Comment: I found that I missed multiplying by X once, would that fix it?

Comment: doubt it,  As long as the value for n is not altered and > 1, it will recurse forever

Comment: Since I know for sure the picture of the algorithm is right (got it from my teacher), where am I mistaken when translating it to C?

Comment: I think it's your use of the "double recursion".  See answer update above