# R: times operation (^)

Tags: c, r, performance, arithmetic-expressions, exponent

I would like to speed up "times" operation(`^`) in R.

```
x <- rnorm(2e+5)
require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(x^(3.33), x^2, x^1, replications = 500)
      test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 x^(3.33)          500    9.22    46.10      9.03     0.04         NA        NA
3      x^1          500    5.47    27.35      5.36     0.10         NA        NA
2      x^2          500    0.20     1.00      0.17     0.04         NA        NA
```

Can I somehow speed up the first operation (`x^(3.33)`)?

Why `x^1` is so slow?

<del>P.S. Where can I find the code of `^` operator?</del>

https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/f68b30e3b5479d84adbff516d48d4722a574dc82/src/main/arithmetic.c#L200

Comment: Improving on .01 seconds to exponentiate 200,000 values suggests you have very high standards.  I'm not sure what the exact algorithm R uses is, but it's probably very similar to one of the C algorithms in a different question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/213043/1017276). Notice the discussion about how the special case of a power of 2 may be shifted for efficiency.

Comment: The source is basically here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/f68b30e3b5479d84adbff516d48d4722a574dc82/src/main/arithmetic.c#L200

Comment: When I run your benchmarks (R 3.4.0, 64-bit MacOS) I get nearly identical results between `x^1` and `x^(3.3)`, so maybe there's a fluke there. `x^1` isn't recognized as a special.  If you really need to speed things up you could probably write Rcpp code to do the multiplication without any checking for infinite/NaN values