# C Trouble with operators

Tags: c

I was trying to do some operations with a n number. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float n;

    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%f",&n);
    printf("n^2 = %f\n",(n^2.0));
    printf("n^3 = %f\n",(n^3.0));
    printf("2^n = %f\n",(2.0^n));
    printf("3^n = %f\n",(3.0^n));

}
```

But when compiling it gives me an error. This is:

```
exercice14.c:10:23: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'double')
printf("n^2 = %f\n",(n^2.0));
                     ~^~~~
exercice14.c:11:23: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'double')
printf("n^3 = %f\n",(n^3.0));
                     ~^~~~
exercice14.c:12:25: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'float')
printf("2^n = %f\n",(2.0^n));
                     ~~~^~
exercice14.c:13:25: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'float')
printf("3^n = %f\n",(3.0^n));
```

Comment: `^` is the **XOR** operator. Use `pow()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you do exponentiation in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213042/how-do-you-do-exponentiation-in-c)

Comment: @xLui In C the sign ^ denotes the bitwise exclusive or operator that may be applied only to objects of integer types.

Comment: For future reference, you should also include what you want the output to be instead and an explanation why.

Comment: As noted above, use `pow()`.  Include `math.h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, `^` is the bitwise XOR operator, not exponentiation. To do exponentiation, use the `pow()` function from `math.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float n;

    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%f",&n);
    printf("n^2 = %f\n",pow(n, 2.0));
    printf("n^3 = %f\n",pow(n, 3.0));
    printf("2^n = %f\n",pow(2.0, n));
    printf("3^n = %f\n",pow(3.0, n));
}
```

You will need the `-lm` compiler flag.